# Minecraft FML Gradle build error "Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12"

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a Forge mod for Minecraft 1.12.2, and I've done everything I can think of, but I always get this error:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - https://maven.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.pom
    - https://maven.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar
    - file:/C:/Users/techi/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I checked if there was anything I was missing in the build.gradle file, which I fixed several issues with, but it still did not work. Then I double-checked that I had copied the MDK correctly, which I had. I tried refreshing the dependencies, which also didn't work.

Comment: Can you add the build.gradle file to the post?